# PHP adding Date - mysqli_stmt::bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I'm trying to add a date field to a from and save to PHP/MySQL database. I'm using phpMyAdmin and have set the 'edate' field to 'DATE' type.

My PHP file to save the data is:

```
$statement = $db->stmt_init();

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$edate =  $_POST['edate'];
$timestamp = date('dd-mm-yyyy', strtotime($edate));  

//database insert statement
$statement->prepare("INSERT INTO events (lat, lon, name, description,    category, edate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '$timestamp')");

//grab values from the url and add to database
$statement->bind_param("ddsssi", $_POST['lat'], $_POST['lon'], $_POST['name'],     $_POST['description'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['edate']);
$status = $statement->execute();
```

But when i run the PHP file in the browser. it gives teh following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /Users/Stephen/Sites/tidy_map/adddata.php on line 18
```

with line 18 being:

```
$statement->bind_param("ddsssi", $_POST['lat'], $_POST['lon'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['edate']);
```

The Form is part of a Google Map using Google Maps API V3 - when a new marker is added to the map, it opens an InfoWindow which displays the form with some Javascript:

```
// Add Foem to New Info Window
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (point)
{
    //"clone" the event-form to put in the infowindow
    var form = $(".event-form").clone().show();
    var infowindow_content = form[0];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: infowindow_content,
    });
```

Comment: Yep, you're right (*or it's right*); doesn't add up. Count them for yourself. 5x questions marks `?, ?, ?, ?, ?` 6x binds `ddsssi`

Comment: replace `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '$timestamp')");` with `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )");`

Comment: When i replace it with "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?", the error is fixed. But now it doesnt save to the DB. The Date format input in the form is: "31/03/2015" for example (using <input type="date">. Then it returns a notification "Column 'edate' cannot be null" when the form is saved.

Comment: MySQL's storage method for datetime is the other way around YYYY-mm-dd https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html - `if(!$statement->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$db->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` would have told you that. Yet, we don't know what type your column is for that one.

Comment: Thats why i originally had "$timestamp = date('dd-mm-yyyy', strtotime($edate));  " in my php to change the date format. So should I change the format that it is input from the form instead??

Comment: If you're using today's date, just use `NOW()` in place of `'$timestamp'`

Comment: It could be any date - it's for adding events which will have a date that it will be taking place

Comment: What is the column's "type" for the one you want to insert the date into?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is "DATE" type. It's just simply going to used to display the date so would it be better to save it as a string?? Maybe use VARCHER?

Comment: Then try changing it to `$timestamp = date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime($edate));` see what that says. But, I don't know what your form looks like for it and how it's being formatted; as a pulldown? other?

Comment: No, don't use VARCHAR, you're going to have a heck of a time querying later.

Comment: Its being used with google maps API - when a new marker is added, it opens an InfoWindow which the form is displayed in.

Comment: Well then, try VARCHAR but like I said; you're going to have a whale of a time querying later. I suggest you post more related/relevant code. If I can't solve it, somebody else will/should. I don't know how their API works.

Comment: Plus, `"ddsssi"` the `i` should be changed to `s` either if your column is `date` or `datetime` or `varchar`. The `i` is for integer which isn't what you're passing through the bind, once you've done that with the 6x `?` marks to match. Probably why.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, bind your timestamp as a string and tell postgres to cast it to a timestamp

```
//database insert statement
$statement->prepare("INSERT INTO events (lat, lon, name, description,    category, edate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, STR_TO_DATE(?,'%d-%m-%Y'))");

//grab values from the url and add to database
$statement->bind_param("ddssss", $_POST['lat'], $_POST['lon'], $_POST['name'],     $_POST['description'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['edate']);
```

Comment: Sorry i miss that, I just edited my answer for mysql, i hope it would work

Comment: Tried this. There are no errors, but it still does not save to the DB. It just says "edate cannot be Null".

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for all the help guys, i actually discovered the problem. The php works ok:

```
//database insert statement
$statement->prepare("INSERT INTO events (lat, lon, name, description, category, edate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

//grab values from the url and add to database
$statement->bind_param("ddssss", $_POST['lat'], $_POST['lon'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['edate']);
```

But I had never added the Date field to be sent from my JS code.

```
edate: $("input[name=edate]",this).val(),
```

It was a total oversight on my part. Thanks for the help and sorry for wasting your time.